# Cordova iOS: xcrun can't find "PackageApplication" after xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, building, xcrun

This morning, xcode got updated to version 8.3 on my osx building device.

Since then, when I try to build my iOs app with Cordova, I get the following error at the end of the building process:

```
 [exec] 
 [exec] ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
 [exec]
 [exec] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH
 [exec] Error: Error code 72 for command: xcrun with args: -sdk,iphoneos,PackageApplication,-v,[source.app]-o,[destination.ipa]
 [exec] Result 1
```

I can't seem to get this fixed in my Cordova or Xcode setup. Wouldn't know where to start ;)

Did anyone experience the same issue? Do you have some advise for a solution.

Thank you!

(I'll be happy to buy a beer if you could help me out)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH - Since updating xCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068608/xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-packageapplication-not-a-developer-tool)

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your ios platform in config.xml:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.3.1" />
```

Then reinstall your platform:

```
rm -rf platforms/
cordova prepare
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a cordova-ios PR (#257, now merged - https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/257) for this issue.

So, updating cordova-ios is the fix.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm searching for some documentation or logging on this, but unfortunately can't seem to find anything.

Do you know where I can find this perhaps, so I can share this to our dev team? 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kickar - Added the PR link above.  Beware, so far in testing it does indeed fix the original issue but appears to have a new issue.  The Cordova clean process will wipe out the platform www directory now, which will cause builds to fail.  At this moment in time I have to recommend NOT running clean.

Comment: Clean issue was an artifact of my environment and is unrelated to the cordova-ios update which will fix the original issue.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I have the exact same issue and I am at cordova-ios 4.3.1, which is the latest release

Answer (score 1):

We only solution we had is:

1. Copied from xcode `Contents\Developer\Platforms\IPhoneOS.platform\DeviceSupport\10.3` folder
2. rolled back to xcode 8.2 but put 10.3 back in `Contents\Developer\Platforms\IPhoneOS.platform\DeviceSupport\`
3. Packaging start working.

Answer (score 0):

After you try to build on device using

```
ionic run ios --device -l -c
```

Open the project on the xCode without terminating the code you typed

Try to run the project on xCode too and tada. It works on phone with debug on terminal.

Answer (score -1):

This tool has been removed from Xcode 8.3.  It was marked as deprecated for a few versions, and now it's sadly gone.

You will need to use [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) and it may be a bit of a pain with Cordova

Comment: "and it may be a bit of a pain with Cordova" - could you please be more specific? thanks ;)