# PAClient Error "paclient" exited with code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, xcode9.2

When I try to Deploy/Run <kbd>F9</kbd> my *FireMonkey* mobile app from a *Win10.1x32* machine to an *Ipad 4 mini*, I get the following error:

> paclient exited with code 1

When I change the build target to *Android*, everything works fine. I used *Delphi Berlin* and *XCode 9.2* and it's my first *iOS* app.

Can anybody give me an advise?

Comment: Consider updating to Tokyo. For Android that is sane advice as well.

Comment: I can't do the updating for now , i hope this isn't the only solution?

Comment: It's likely that Delphi 10.1 Berlin will not work with Xcode 9.2, so it may be the only solution. In Delphi, check the "Output" tab of the messages window - it has more detail. You should add this to your question

Comment: In  the message window i don't have an error message:
paclient pour "Mac"
 ' c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 --codesign="TestApp.app,'iPhone Developer: Mahmoud 
  (275ZFFMCU4)',TestApp.app\..\TestApp.entitlements"  Mac' 
[PAClient Erreur] "paclient" exited with code 1.
Echec

Comment: my ipad is in IOS 11.2.5, if i change xcode 9.2 to a previous version like 9.0 it can work?

Comment: I think it needs to be Xcode 8.2.2 or lower to work with Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Comment: I tried with Xcode 8.2 and Xcode 8.0 but the same problem, and i don't know but my ipad os is 11.2.5, so it's possible to make it ith Xcode 8.2? because Xcode max is Ios 10

Comment: Dave Nottage. This  is incorrect. I worked with Delphi Berlin with Xcode 9.1 and iOS 11.1  because Tokyo is buggy.  Just need to copy special file to Mac (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068608/xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-packageapplication-not-a-developer-tool   - choose best answer), BUT for iOS 11.2.5 need Xcode 9.2 or 9.3 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777075/trying-to-compile-ios-device-64-bit-in-delphi).

Comment: Updated comment: Dave Nottage. This  is incorrect. I worked with Delphi Berlin with Xcode 9.1 and iOS 11.1  because Tokyo is buggy (especially for Android).  Just need to copy special file to Mac, BUT for iOS 11.2.5 need Xcode 9.2 or 9.3 . I could not start an app with SDK iOS 11.2, but could do it with previous versions - 11 and 10, maybe you should find iPhone with older iOS.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777075/trying-to-compile-ios-device-64-bit-in-delphi).

Comment: (https://community.embarcadero.com/answers/xcode-8-3 
 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068608/xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-packageapplication-not-a-developer-tool   - choose best answer)

Comment: ok, thank you, i'll try with an older iOs, i think it's better for the moment because even with Tokyo i have the same problem