# Trying to compile iOS device 64-bit in Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2 Update 3, with an iOS target of 11.3 and an iPad running iOS 10.3.3.

When I try to compile my project for a iOS device, this error occurs:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:\Users\gustavo.reinert\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.3.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks'
  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LC:\Users\Marcio.Amorim\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\MacOSX10.13.sdk\usr\lib\system'
  ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture arm64
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Delphi bug when compiling against iOS 11.3 SDK.

[RSP-20303: XCode 9.3 and iOS 11.3 linker error](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20303)

You can use iOS 11.2 SDK instead.

Comment: how can i download this version?

Comment: AFAIK, it comes with Xcode 9.2 that can be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: So should I install Xcode 9.2 instead of 9.3? Or can I compile with Xcode 9.3 for iOS SDK 11.2? Thank you.