# Delphi PAClient Error: E0776 xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Delphi 10.2.3 deploying to Application Store gets this error:

`[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH`

The recommended solution in this question did not solve the problem. 
[xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH - Since updating xCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068608/xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-packageapplication-not-a-developer-tool)

I downloaded the PackageApplication script, placed it inside of Xcode.app, and ran the chmod command.
chmod +x /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication

The error persists.

Where does Delphi and/or Xcode expect this PackageApplication script to be?

Comment: The most recent version of Delphi does not expect PackageApplication to be anywhere. Please ensure you have build (in Help|About) 25.0.31059.3231, and that PAServer reports that it is version 10.3.1.15, when it starts. Also, what version of Xcode do you have? It should be at least Xcode 9.2. You may need to install this patch if you have not already done so: https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30837

Comment: Huh. My Delphi reports 10.2 Update 3 but says the build is 25.0.29899.2631. PAServer is 10.2.1.13.  (Xcode 9.4.1, which I was told was the latest that Delphi 10.2.3 supported.)

How in the world did I miss an update?

Comment: @DaveNottage I went and applied that IDE patch to Delphi (consisting mostly of copying lots of newer .bpl files) but when I run it I still get the same build number for Delphi. That is, my bds.exe still remains build 25.0.29899.2631. How does one get that newer build that you have?

I'm going to try applying the PAServer portion of the patch to see if it resolves my issue though.

Comment: Applying the PAServer portion of the patch did update the PAServer to 10.3.1.35. However, the error still persists. I'm assuming that means my Delphi 10.2.3 is still asking the PAServer to use PackageApplication.

Comment: The patch will not update the build number. As far as I can recall, that patch requires manually replacing a bunch of files. Did you make sure all were replaced? An alternative might be to reinstall Delphi (make sure you use bin\MigrationTool.exe first to save all your settings before uninstalling) using this: https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally fixed this was downloading a fresh copy of Xcode 9.4.1 and then deploying a blank app from Xcode - which is apparently essential. Right after that, Delphi created an .ipa file for the application store.